# Rundeck nodes when using Terraform

Tags: rundeck

**Background:** We are exploring whether to use Jenkins or RunDeck to do the deployments. If I look at RunDeck documentation, it suggests to use Jenkins as a Build tool and RunDeck as an Operations tool. It suggests to build using Jenkins and then invoke a RunDeck job to get the build deployed. We are also using Packer and Terraform combine to create images and environments respectively.

One of main advantages listed against RunDeck is that it understands the concept of nodes (which makes it environment aware) and this is something Jenkins cannot do.

**Question:** Since infrastructure is created using Terraform, Terraform is aware about the VMs created. It can definitely return the list of VM IPs but then why would I need to use the concept of RunDeck nodes if environment is managed through Terraform? If I need to do anything with respect to VMs, then I can simply use Terraform itself.

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck Model Sources (or "nodes") is for executing actions (commands or jobs) against them, you can create all the infrastructure using Terraform (as you said) in a job (or using [this](https://github.com/MegaDrive68k/rundeck-terraform-steps-plugin) community plugin), reload the model source using [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-steps/builtin.html#refresh-project-nodes) step, and then use the [EC2 model source](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin) to get the nodes (or any other Model Source generated by the first step) and launch any job/command against those nodes later.